# What's the security issue with base64 encoding/decoding?

Tags: php, vulnerability

http://phptester.net/ yields the warning

> WARNING base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons

Why?

**Besides the obvious vulnerabilities that have nothing to do with base64_decode** (treating it as encryption, as a hash, evaluating base64_decoded data, etc) **why would simply executing it** be a security vulnerability?

Comment: Probably because phptester has some major vulnerabilities, and one of the exploits required in base64_decode, so they decided to disable it. Based on that theory, I wouldn't be surprised if their security was something like: `if(strstr($code, "eval") !== false || strstr($code, "readfile") !== false || ...) {echo "Security fail!"; exit;}`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> why would simply executing it be a security vulnerability?

It's not.

`base64_decode` does exactly what you would expect: It decodes a string.

There are also no know vulnerabilities in it, nor have there been in the past (there was an integer overflow issue in `base64_encode` -  CVE-2003-0861 - but PHP does not consider it a security issue).

I would assume that http://phptester.net/ bans it because it can be used to obfuscate data. They may have some filters in place to prevent execution of dangerous code and may worry that `base64_decode` could be used to bypassed these filters. I don't think that this is necessary or useful, but that might be their train of thought.

Comment: Arguably the dumbest part of that line of reasoning is that a malicious user could probably just write their own decoder.

Comment: @jpmc26 Someone actually wrote most of PHP in PHP, so yeah... The work is already done! :P https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHPPHP

Comment: phptester.net does not allow `eval` anyways, so it's not like you can stuff the output of `base64_decode` into `eval`.